# .Net MAUI, Adding a constructor causes "Flyout and Detail must be set before adding FlyoutPage to a container"

Tags: c#, maui, flyout

I am new to .NET MAUI and making a page "`MainPage`" with flyoutPage.
In the page, I have values bounded from `MainPageViewModel` and `Flyout`.

When I try to set `BindingContext` in `MainPage.xaml.cs`, I get `Flyout and Detail must be set before adding FlyoutPage to a container` error.

But if I add `InitializeComponent()` to the first constructor with no parameter, it stops complaining about it.

Is keeping both of `InitializeComponent()` the right way to fix this? Or am I missing something else?

In MainPage.xaml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Realizer.ViewModels"
            xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Realizer.Models"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Realizer.Pages"
            x:Class="Realizer.Pages.MainPage"
            x:DataType="vm:MainPageViewModel"
            Title="Home">

    <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <ContentPage Title="Home page" BackgroundColor="LightGrey">
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <CollectionView>
                    <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type models:Flyout}">
                            <models:Flyout Title="Home"
                                       IconSource="home.png"
                                       Command="GoToHomePageCommand"/>
                            <models:Flyout Title="Clients"
                                        IconSource="person.png"
                                        Command="GoToClientsPageCommand"/>
                        </x:Array>
                    </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Padding="20, 5">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding IconSource, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:Flyout}}}"
                                   Scale="1.5"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Text="{Binding Title, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:Flyout}}}"
                                    Command="{Binding Command, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:Flyout}}}"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    HeightRequest="60"
                                    Padding="0,0,110,0"
                                    BackgroundColor="LightGray"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
                <Label Text="this is it"
                       Margin="20"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>

    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor="Navy"
                        BarTextColor="Black"
                        Title="Home">
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage Title="Home" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="this is detail"
                           Margin="20"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Realizer.ViewModels;

namespace Realizer.Pages;

public partial class MainPage : FlyoutPage
{
    public MainPage(){
        //InitializeComponent();

    }

    public MainPage(MainPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }


}
```

In MainPageViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Realizer.Pages;

namespace Realizer.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        { 
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task GoToClientsPage()
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ClientsPage());
        }
    }
}
```

In App.xaml.cs

```
using Realizer.Pages;

namespace Realizer
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call code  `MainPage = new MainPage();` to `MainPage`, it will call the default constructor(no parameter) of `MainPage` to initialize data for this page.

From document [Get started with XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/get-started?view=net-maui-8.0),we could find that :

> The MainPage constructor calls `InitializeComponent`, which initializes
> all the objects defined in the XAML file, connects them all together
> in parent-child relationships, attaches event handlers defined in code
> to events set in the XAML file, and sets the resultant tree of objects
> as the content of the page.

So, we should call method `InitializeComponent()` to initialize all the objects defined in the XAML file after navigating to this page by code  `MainPage = new MainPage();`. Otherwise, the code will report the error you mentioned.